# How do I animate adding subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I animate adding sub views to a view?

I know it animates when you use a navigation controller however is it possible to animate around this code:

```
[self.view addSubview:myVC.view];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a 'CATransition' or a `UIView` animation, depending on what animation you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

[iphone-sdk-animating-subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926971/iphone-sdk-animating-subview)